# How to remotely host my c++ game server on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, server, hosting

I made a server for a 3D multiplayer game I'm working on. The game is currently functional to a point where I know multiplayer gameplay is possible locally on Windows.

IDE: Visual Studio 2019 
Target platforms: Windows & Ubuntu
Server linked libraries: winmm.lib, ws2_32.lib, sfml-system-s-d.lib, sfml-network-s-d.lib

I want the server to work on a remotely hosted dedicated server where I have Ubuntu installed, and to be capable of connecting the client locally from Windows, **how should I do this? Considering the following:**

- My project currently uses the visual C++ compiler from VS, 
  which I presume makes my own c++ code only work on windows (correct?).
- I've done some simple aplications for Ubuntu in C++, and know that
  for an aplication to work on Ubuntu, it needs to be compiled using
  the g++ compiler, however, this doesn't seem to be an option on my
  current environment.
- Also, 2 of the libraries my sfml dependencies depend on, seem to be
  designed for windows (This could mean issues with the sfml modules I'm 
  using?).
- Finally, I also know there could be some endianness issues, for now 
  I did a quick check and found out both my local, and remote cpu's,
  use little endian formats.

Additional note: I really could just install any other OS on my remote machine, including Windows, but I like Ubuntu's lightweightness, and I'm familiar with the OS.

Comment: SFML does support Linux. It should be perfectly possible to compile a program depending on SFML for Linux. If it doesn't work, then the problem must be something else.

Comment: Ok, I actually asked some time ago on SFML's discord server if that would be the case, and they did indeed confirm what you are saying. But those two depending windows libraries still worry me (I guess maybe they shouldn't, as long as they're there which is all sfml requests), and I still wouldn't know how to do this considering my starting point is a VS project.

Comment: Perhaps there is something else in your servers dependencies which relies on some windows-only library? Winsock perhaps? (wild guess)

Comment: If you are questioning if I'm using the winsock library myself directly, then the answer is no. Edit: not using winmm.lib directly either, and don't have any other libraries linked to the server (besides a custom one I built, which uses no extra libraries).

Comment: Wait, didn't you write that your program depends on ws2_32.lib? (also known as Winsock 2)

Comment: Yeah, that's because the sfml networking module depends on it.

Comment: On windows... When you compile SFML on UNIX then it depends on POSIX sockets instead. There doesn't seem to be a reason why your server should not be able to compile on Linux. Maybe you could post your makefile and the error log of g++?

Comment: Actually I don't even know how I could compile my VS project using g++ instead of visual  c++, locally. That's one of my doubts. This question is mainly doubts and asking for advice, no errors yet.

Comment: Maybe this article from Microsoft about creating a UNIX makefile from a Visual Studio project could help you? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/creating-a-makefile-project?view=vs-2019